# Find the sum of some numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I have a number $a=3145$.At first exercise I need to find how many numbers can be formed with the digits of a. $4!=24$ numbers.My problem is at second exercise where I need to find the sum of these numbers.

How to start?

Answer (score 1):

How many numbers have a $3$ in the ones place?  There are the same number that have each digit in the ones place.  What is the sum of the column of numbers in the ones place?  The sum of the digits in each other place is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: each digit can be in either the first, second, third or fourth position, where it is multiplied by $10^3$, $10^2$, $10^1$ or $10^0$.  On the average it is multiplied by $1111/4$.